# How to convert a nested list to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and am trying to convert a nested list object into a dataframe so I may use it in an r program.

The object is named 'positions' and here is the data in that object:

```
[
    Position(account='DU1340125', 
             contract=Future(conId=138979241, symbol='CL'), 
             position=1.0, avgCost=60022.37), 
    Position(account='DU1340125', 
             contract=Future(conId=321454633, symbol='YM'), 
             position=1.0, avgCost=129302.05)
]


df = pd.DataFrame([positions])
```

The dataframe I want to see would look like:

```
account     Future.conId Future.symbol position avgCost  
'DU1340125' 138979241    'CL'          1.0      60022.37  
'DU1340125' 321454633    'YM'          1.0      129302.05
```

The result I get is:

```
0  (DU1340125, Future(conId=138979241, symbol='CL'...  
   (DU1340125, Future(conId=321454633, symbol='YM'...
```

Comment: You have a `Position` object that we don't have access to. Si it is hard to provide an exact solution. However, it seems that you need to explicitly access the properties, i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame([[p.account, p.future.conId, p.future.symbol, p.position, p.avgcost] for p in positions])`

Comment: @RafaelC probably `p.contract.condId` etc. though ;-)

Comment: @RafaelC The `Position` object is generated from an external API.  Is there a way for me to add the `Position` object to my Stack Overflow example?  I'm not getting the result I had hoped for with the code you suggested, as it gets the same result as `df = pd.DataFrame ([positions])`

Comment: @SNovogoratz We'll, it definitely shouldn't yield the same result, so you are probably doing something wrong there. But is is really hard for us to help without a [mcve]